# Find circular path from A to B passing trought C

Tags: python, path-finding

Lets assume we ve the matrix below, i've already highlighted the supposed optimal path.

```
1 -> locked nodes
0 -> free nodes

[[1, A, ─, ─, C],
 [1, |, 0, 0, |],
 [1, └, ─, ┐, |],
 [1, 1, 1, |, |],
 [1, 1, 1, B, ┘]]
```

Is there any efficient algorithm that support this logic?

My actual algo is a double DFS but result is very inefficient with matrix above 7x7

IDK about nodes traversing order

Current most efficient solution:

```
class Point(complex):

    def dist(self, other):
        return abs(self.real-other.real) + abs(self.imag-other.imag)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.real, self.imag))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.real == other.real and self.imag == other.imag
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return abs(self) < abs(other)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(complex.__add__(self, other))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'P({int(self.real)},{int(self.imag)})'

def find_path(self, A, B, C):
    # self.av_xy => availables points in the map
    # ( min of distance A -> B, A -> C, [A], C found, B found )
    q = [(min(A.dist(B), A.dist(C)), [A], False, False)]
    heapq.heapify(q)

    while q:
        _, path, cf, bf = heapq.heappop(q)

        curr_pos = path[-1]

        if curr_pos == C:
            cf = True
        if not bf and curr_pos == B:
            bf = True
            path.pop(0) # remove A from path so we can get there again
        if cf and bf and curr_pos == A:
            return path

        for new_pos in [curr_pos + o for o in [1, 1j, -1, -1j]]:
            if new_pos not in path and new_pos in self.av_xy:
                newd = new_pos.dist(A if bf else B)
                cd = new_pos.dist(C) if not cf else float('inf')
                heapq.heappush(q, (min(newd, cd), path + [new_pos], cf, bf))
```

Comment: I think you should take a look to the A* algorithm. A* can quickly reach the goal and avoid some "locked" nodes regarding the chosen heuristic. Btw, the title mismatch with the example (regarding C).

Comment: Why mismatch? C needs to be in the final path, idk if C is found during A -> B or B -> A.

Comment: You could use two simple recursive pathfinding algorithms to find the paths AC and CB. Or you can define all free paths as nodes in a network connecting to the (maximal) four adjacent nodes with unweighted edges and use Djikstra's Algorithm to find the fastest path.